# Neo4j - Discriminating relationships based on end node sub class type

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I notice when inheritence is used in a spring-data-neo4j 4 data model, the super class is used as the discriminator when loading and discriminating relationships based on end node type. Is there any way I can force spring-data-neo4j-4 to use a subclass as the discriminator instead?

For example, let's say we have a data model (class diagram) as the following on the left and its neo4j database representation on the right.

[image: Class diagram and neo4j representation]

Currently, if we have an Owner entity with code along the lines of:

```
@NodeEntity
class Owner extends BaseNodeEntity {

    ...

    @Relationship(type="OWNS")
    private Set<Dog> dogs; // both dog and cat are mapped here

    @Relationship(type="OWNS")
    private Set<Cat> cats; // both dog and cat are mapped here

    ...
}
```

The spring-data-neo4j-4 framework will automatically map both Dog and Cat to the set of Cats, and the set of Dogs, so I then have two 'dogs' (although one of them is actually a cat), and two 'cats', (although one of them is actually a dog) loaded from the database. If I remove the super classes Pet and BaseNodeEntity from the data model, then Dog and Cat are automatically mapped to their respective sets correctly.

Is there a way that I can force spring-data-neo4j-4 to map my data model correctly, or will I be forced to change my data model? I'm not keen to remove super classes from my data model as I have a lot of re-use going on, and adding extra relationships (i.e. splitting OWNS to CAT_OWNER and DOG_OWNER) would be similarly annoying.

**Update**

I've now noticed this behaviour is not consistent. I've written a unit tests that tests the mappings. Strangely, sometimes it passes and sometimes it fails (sometimes it erroneously maps the cat as a dog and the dog as a cat and sometimes it doesn't). Manually running the unit test 10 times gave me the following pass / fail results.

```
Run, Result (pass / fail)
1   P
2   F
3   F
4   P
5   F
6   P
7   F
8   F
9   P
10  F
```

Surely mapping behaviour should be consistent. Could this be a bug in SDN-4?

**Update 08 May 2016**

Sorry about the delay in updating this. I've only just had the opportunity to start working on this project again. I have retested this and am getting the same results with the latest stable neo4j release.

```
<neo4j.version>2.3.2</neo4j.version>
<sdn.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</sdn.version>
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
<neo4j-ogm.version>2.0.1</neo4j-ogm.version>
<spring-data-commons.version>1.12.1.RELEASE</spring-data-commons.version>
```

I've attached below the actual domain model used in our test case. The test case details can be seen at https://github.com/johndeverall/thescene-spa/issues/142. The test case code is:

```
    @Test
    public void saveAndLoadTags() { 
        log.info("Given we have a member with some events");
        Member member = createMember();
        Event event1 = eventService.createEvent("Event1", member);
        Event event2 = eventService.createEvent("Event2", member);

        log.info("When I tag my events with some tags");
        contentService.tag("Tag1", "", event1, member);
        contentService.tag("Tag1", "", event1, member); // should create no new tags or relationships
        contentService.tag("Tag2", "", event1, member);
        contentService.tag("Tag2", "", event2, member);

        log.info("Then my events should be appropriately tagged");
        event1 = eventService.loadEventBySceneId(event1.getSceneId());
        assertThat(event1.getTags().size(), is(equalTo(2)));
        assertThat(event2.getTags().size(), is(equalTo(1)));

        log.info("And I should have created two tags total");
        Iterator<Tag> iterator = contentService.getAllTags().iterator();
        List<Tag> tags = StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, Spliterator.ORDERED), false).collect(Collectors.<Tag> toList());
        assertThat(tags.size(), is(equalTo(2)));

        log.info("And our member should have created two tags");
        member = memberService.loadMemberByEmailAddressPasswordAccount(emailAddress);

        // **************************************************************
        // member.getCreatedTags().size() more often than not returns 3   causing my test failure!
        // **************************************************************
        assertThat(member.getCreatedTags().size(), is(equalTo(2)));
    }
```

**The problem shown by the test case**

The following method:

```
public Member loadMemberByEmailAddressPasswordAccount(String emailAddress) { 
        Filter filter = new Filter("email", emailAddress);
        Collection<EmailAddressPasswordAccount> emailAddressPasswordAccounts = session.loadAll(EmailAddressPasswordAccount.class, filter, 2);
        return emailAddressPasswordAccounts.isEmpty() ? null : emailAddressPasswordAccounts.iterator().next().getMember();
    }
```

Returns a Member object that has a Set of createdTags containing 2 Tags and a tag that is actually an Event.

**My actual domain model is below (not simplified to Dogs and Cats):**

[image: OGM Diagram]

**Additional info:**

I have tried annotating all model objects apart from BaseNodeEntity with @NodeEntity annotation. Properties are annotated.

**Update 09 May 2016**

I get the same intermittent results if I swap out the ogm code for loadMemberByEmailAddressPasswordAccount with derived finder on a repository.

Comment: Thanks for the code, I'll take a look

Comment: I've opened https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/161

Comment: Thank you, and thank you for your code. You're amazing! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case above which involved collections of relationships with the same type but different end node types was a bug- http://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/161

This has been fixed and is available in Neo4j OGM 2.0.2

Comment: Thank you Luanne! Have incorporated the new release into our latest build and our internal tests for this all pass now :)